# Get response and returncode from Alertpay return url

Tags: php, payment, payment-processing

I added a alertpay button so that members of my site can pay for premium service. While creating the button I had entered 'http://mywebsite.com/success' as return page.
Alertpay dev guide has information regarding response format and the list of fields and their value for successful transaction.

For eg:

> RETURNCODE    Transaction code number. Please refer to Return Code Table
>   for a list of success and error codes. Ex: RETURNCODE= 202

My question is in PHP how do I check what returncode it is returning?

I want to check if the payment is successful so that the user's account is converted to premium once the payment is received.

Comment: Do a `var_dump(array('POST'=>$_POST,'GET'=>$_GET));` on your success page to see what alertpay actually submits, and in what way.